# error in a search function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, search

I am trying to return contact info for "steve", but codecademy is telling me that it is not returning correctly.

> It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Steve.

I am not able to find any error in this code. Can you help me with finding any syntax or logical errors in the search function that you can see?

```
var friends = {
    bill: {
        firstName: "bill",
        lastName: "gates",
        number :21415,
        address: ["mcklsn", "wcnskln"]
    },
    Steve: {
        firstName: "bill",
        lastName: "gates",
        number: 21415,
        address: ["mcklsn", "wcnskln"]
    }
};

var list = function (friends)
{
    for (bill in friends)
        console.log(bill);

    for (steve in friends)
        console.log(steve);
};

var search = function(name)
{
    for (var i in friends)
    {
        if (friends[i].firstName === name)
        {
            console.log(friends[i]);
            return friends[i];
        }
        else
            console.log("contact doesn't exist!");
    } 
};
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @Idos the compiler is saying  "It looks like your search function doesn't return contact information for Steve.". really dn't know how to fix it?!

Comment: @Idos well i am learning js in codecademy and the error is shown exactly like this. it's unedited.

Comment: @DanLowe how to make it into an array?

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved your question (by clicking the green check mark next to it).

Answer (score 1):

You should really pay attention to what you are writing, don't Ctrl-C Ctrl-V everything blindly. You are not calling your `friends` in the correct names and I would be offended if someone did that to me. Heck, Steve Jobs would be **furious** if you called him Bill!

This should work:

```
var friends = {
    Bill: {
        firstName: "Bill",
        lastName: "Gates",
        number: 21415,
        address: ["mcklsn", "wcnskln"]
    },
    Steve: {
        firstName: "Steve",
        lastName: "Jobs",
        number: 21416,
        address: ["mcklsnn", "wcnsklnn"]
    }
};

search("Bill");
search("Steve");
```

Answer (score 0):

Yah, because your `Steve` property object's `firstName` is set to `"bill"`.

So that code, searching for a match to 'steve' on the `firstName` property will not find one...because there isn't one. Both of those object's have 'bill' as their `firstName` property.